# Proof verification: Rudin 6c.

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Let $B(r) = \{b^t \mid t\text{ is  rational},\ t < r\}$. Show that $b^r = \sup B(r).$

My proof is as follows:

Clearly $b^r$ is an upper bound on B(r).

Suppose $y < b^r$. By problem 7, we know there exists a unique real $x$ such that $b^x = y$.

Thus $b^x < b^r$, which implies that $x < r$ (this is the concerning leap). By denseness of R, there exists rational $q$ satisfying $x < q < r$. We know that $b^x = y < b^q$ and as $b^q \in B(r)$, we have shown $y$ is not an upper bound on $B(r)$.

As any $y < b^r$ ceases to be an upper bound on B(r), this proves that $b^r = \sup B(r)$.

I think the concerning part comes from my assumption that $x < y \iff b^x < b^y$ whenever $b > 1$.

Comment: From an axiomatic viewpoint,  we $define$ $b^r=\sup B(r)$ when $b>0$ and $r\not \in \Bbb Q$, and then show that it has the intuitively desired properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b>1$, your claim is that $x<y \iff b^x < b^y$.  Another way of saying this is that $$f(x)=b^x$$ is a strictly increasing function for $b>1$. But this is clear if you draw the graph for any $b$.

---

One way to show it analytically could be to consider the derivative, $$f'(x)=b^x \ln(b)$$Notice that $b^x>0$ for all $x$, and $\ln(b)>0$ since $b>1$.  So together this means $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$, so $f$ is increasing